# Change a column in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.  Kendo UI grids calls to Web API controller to retrieve the data.  I have a requirement to change the contents of a column depending on what Fuel type car is.  So on my model for the page I created a string for Fuel Type.  In MVC controller this is then set as below:

```
model.FuelType = "Diesel"; //just hardcoded for testing in reality will be dynamically set by User in a Previous screen - could be set to Petrol in which case I need to change column data
```

On a partial view I have my Kendo UI Grid defined as below - also on the PartialView I have a html.hiddenfor to store the value of FuelType

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Car.Web.Models.CarViewModel>()
                          .Name("CarViewGrid")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(c => c.Make).Width(180);
                              columns.Bound(c => c.ModelNo).Width(280);
                              columns.Bound(c => c.EngineSize).Width(120);
                              columns.Bound(c => c.Colour).Width(65);
                              columns.Bound(c => c.MPG).Width(65);

                              columns.Bound(c => c.CarId)
                                  .Title("Include in Report")
                                  .ClientTemplate("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selectedIds\" value=\"#=CarId#\" class=\"checkboxClass\" />")
                                      .Width(90)
                                      .Sortable(false); 
                          })
                          .Events(builder => builder.DataBound("gridDataBound"))
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 420px;" })
                          .Scrollable()
                          .Sortable(sortable => sortable
                              .AllowUnsort(true)
                              .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                          .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                              .PageSizes(true)
                              .ButtonCount(5))
                          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                              .Ajax()
                             .Read(read => read.Url("api/Car/GetCarDetails").Type(HttpVerbs.Get).Data("GetCustId"))
                          )
                          )
```

I have left a line blank in my column and that is where I need to include a different column  - if the FuelTyle is Petrol I need to have

```
columns.Bound(c => c.NumberSparkPlugs).Width(65);
```

but if the FuelType is Diesel I need to have

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Torque).Width(65);
```

Both of these are string properties on my CarViewModel.

Has anyone done something similar with Kendo UI Grid or can advise in the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Kendo MVC project in VisualStudio to test this with, but can't you just use an `if` statement:

```
                      .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Bound(c => c.Make).Width(180);
                          columns.Bound(c => c.ModelNo).Width(280);
                          columns.Bound(c => c.EngineSize).Width(120);
                          columns.Bound(c => c.Colour).Width(65);
                          columns.Bound(c => c.MPG).Width(65);

                          columns.Bound(c => c.CarId)
                              .Title("Include in Report")
                              .ClientTemplate("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selectedIds\" value=\"#=CarId#\" class=\"checkboxClass\" />")
                                  .Width(90)
                                  .Sortable(false); 

// added code here...
                          if(Model.FuelType == "Petrol")
                              columns.Bound(c => c.NumberSparkPlugs).Width(65);
                          else
                              columns.Bound(c => c.Torque).Width(65);
                      })
```